# jersey webservice not returning jsonp

Tags: jsonp, jersey

I am trying to create a webservice that will return jsonp.
At the moment it is only returning json

Here is my code:

```
@Path("/jsonp")
public class JsonpWebservice {

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public JSONWithPadding readAllP(@QueryParam("jsoncallback") @DefaultValue("jsoncallback") String jsoncallback) 
    {
        ToolKitBean tkBean = new ToolKitBean();
        tkBean.setNegativeCount("10");
        tkBean.setPositiveCount("11");

        System.out.println("jsoncallback: " + jsoncallback); 
        return new JSONWithPadding( new GenericEntity<ToolKitBean>(tkBean) {}, jsoncallback);

    }   

}
```

i also have a JAXBContext resolver defined.
When i look at the response from this webservice, I see the json and not jsonp  - `{"negativeCount":"10","positiveCount":"11"}`

Any ideas what I need to do in order to have jsonP returned from this webservice?

Thanks
DAmien

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By changing 
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})  to be
    @Produces("application/x-javascript")

This has fixed my issue

Thanks
Damien